# iOS segues data not being passed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Data is not being passed from one VC to another, can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm trying to pass an NSURL or NSURLRequest and when I log out the request/url object on the second VC, I get null.

First VC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ILAuthClient.h"
#import "ILAuthLoginViewController.h"

@interface ILViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *request;
@end
```

First VC.m (relevant section)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"authLogin"]){
        NSURL *url = [self authenticateWithInstagram];
        ILAuthLoginViewController *authModal = [[ILAuthLoginViewController alloc]init];
        authModal.delegate = self;
        authModal.url = url;}
```

Second VC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ILAuthLoginViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLRequest *request;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;

@end
```

Second VC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:self.url];

    [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];
    NSLog(@"Request %@", self.request);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter `prepareForSegue` your second view controller has already been allocated for you and is available as the `destinationViewController` property on the segue.  You are allocating a new one and assigning properties but this object isn't used.

Your method should be

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"authLogin"]){
        NSURL *url = [self authenticateWithInstagram];
        ILAuthLoginViewController *authModal = (ILAuthLoginViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        authModal.delegate = self;
        authModal.url = url;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line ...

```
    ILAuthLoginViewController *authModal = [[ILAuthLoginViewController alloc]init];
```

should be changed to this

```
    ILAuthLoginViewController * authModal = (ILAuthLoginViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
```

The one you are `alloc`ing isn't the one the storyboard is presenting

Answer (score 3):

Two things to check for.

`1.`Your call is wrong while passing through segue. It should be

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"authLogin"]){
            NSURL *url = [self authenticateWithInstagram];
            ILAuthLoginViewController *authModal = (ILAuthLoginViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            authModal.delegate = self;
            authModal.url = url;
        }
 }
```

`2.`Make sure your `url string` is well formed.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"YOURURL" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Hope its helpful.